# Implicit animation on padding

Tags: flutterflow

I need to add a swift animation to an image, so I wrapped it on a container to do so, but I don't know why, the container doesn't implicit animate when its padding its changed, not like when you change the color of the container or its size.

When I try to ''implicit animate'' the change of padding values it does it instantly, its really blocky and not crisp at all.

I tried to add a page state variable and link the padding value to that variable, when pressed a button that page state variable is set to a certain value which in turn changed the value of the padding, it works but its really blocky, I want to make a swift animation when doing this proceadure